# How to turn on Cron Job only on sundays but every second?

Tags: node.js, cron

How can if I have this starting CronJob template:

```
   const job = new CronJob(
  '* * * * * *',
  function () {

    console.log('You will see this message every second');
  },
  null,
  true,
  'America/Los_Angeles'
);
job.start();
```

How can I make this cronJob work only on sundays but every second on sundays?

Answer (score 1):

maybe you can check what day today is first
and then make a condition if the day is sunday

```
const days = ["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"];
const dayName = days[new Date().getDay()];

if(dayName === 'Sun'){
  const job = new CronJob(
  '* * * * * *',
  function () {
  // do something here
  },
  null,
  true,
  'America/Los_Angeles'
);
job.start();
}
```

Comment: If I'm running this in an node express server, will dayName always check the condition?